# jquery click не работает

Tags: jquery, click

Почему автоматически не срабатывает ссылка?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  $("#tab-title-tab3").click( function(){
   $("#mylink").click(); 
 }); 
});
```

Сама ссылка:

```
<a href="http://example.ru/" id="mylink">Я ссылка</a>
```

Comment: а что вы по клику сделать хотели?

Comment: Чтобы совершился переход по ссылке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#tab-title-tab3").click(function() {
    $("#mylink")[0].click();
  });
});
```

```css
#mylink {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" id="mylink">Я ссылка</a>
<button type="button" id="tab-title-tab3">Button</button>
```

Comment: Отлично работает!!! Спасибо. Только зачем вот эти строчки: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <button type="button" id="tab-title-tab3">Button</button>` ?? И можно скрыть с экрана вот эту строчку? `<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/" id="mylink">Я ссылка</a>` ??

Comment: @ЮляФролова эти строчки - чтобы работал пример в ответе

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. По поводу `display:none;` - думала работать ссылка не будет если через цсс скрыть) Спасибо.

Comment: @ЮляФролова Пожалуйста. Успехов!